# wine doesn't work with cron

Tags: linux, cron, wine

I cannot for the life of me get wine to work with cron. It just straight up doesn't work. I get this error each time:

```
wine: '/' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there
```

Note, I am running under the correct user (not attempting to run the command as root).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Additional information, the cron entry looks something like this:

```
01 01 * * 1-5 username cd /prog/location; ./wineprogram.exe
```

EDIT2: wineprogram.exe is command line only, it does not pop up any windows, i know the cron user has no x11

Comment: What about posting the cron entry you are referring to? How are we meant to help without?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the cron entry. It is just something like this: 01 01 * * 1-5 username cd /prog/location; ./wineprogram.exe

Comment: Try using a login shell, most likely your environment is not setup correctly during the cron ecxecution. Something like this: `bash -l -c "cd /prog/location; ./wineprogram.exe"`

Comment: I doubt it. There's no reason it's not already bash -cl. The error message is clearly wine environment related. EDIT: tested anyways, same error msg still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `$WINEPREFIX` that would be used as that user.

Comment: Can you provide some clarification? How and where do I set the $WINEPREFIX in the cron?

Comment: `env WINEPREFIX=... ./wineprogram.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Wine works with cron but it needs to know which display to use, I was able to run wine scripts by the following way:

Determine which display is your user using

```
user:~$echo $DISPLAY
```

outputs:

```
:0
```

*(above this can be different in your case!)*

Then edit crontab like this:

```
26 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/wine /path/to/app/you/want.exe
```

Also if your wine is on different location try with:

```
which wine
```